# Launch JVM through JNI_CreateJavaVM in OSX is console-only

Tags: cocoa, jvm, java-native-interface, jvm-arguments

I am trying to launch JVM from my C/ObjC program, but I have some issues displaying visual elements, like for example a window, on Catalina.

The part of the program that uses non-visual items, i.e. console & `System.out` works fine. But not any application window appears, although a proper Dock icon appears, which when clicked it does nothing.

I have written a helper function, to launch JVM. As arguments it has

- the location of the `libjvm.dylib`
- the JVM options
- the size of the jvm options
- the main arguments
- the size of the main arguments
- the main class

I looks to me that I am missing something, but I can't figure out what. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```c
typedef jint (*JNI_CreateJavaVM_f)(JavaVM **, void **, void *);

int launchjvm(char *jvmlib, char **jvmopts, int c_jvmopts, char **args, int c_args, char *mainclass)
{
    JavaVM *vm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[c_jvmopts];

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < c_jvmopts; i++)
        options[i].optionString = jvmopts[i];
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.nOptions = c_jvmopts;

    void *lib_handle = dlopen(jvmlib, RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!lib_handle)
    {
        printf("[%s] Unable to load library: %s\n", __FILE__, dlerror());
        return 1;
    }
    JNI_CreateJavaVM_f JNI_CreateJavaVM = dlsym(lib_handle, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
    if (!JNI_CreateJavaVM)
    {
        printf("[%s] Unable to get symbol: %s\n", __FILE__, dlerror());
        return 1;
    }

    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
    if (res != JNI_OK)
    {
        printf("Failed to create Java VM\n");
        return res;
    }

    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, mainclass);
    if (cls == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to find %s class\n", mainclass);
        return 1;
    }

    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if (mid == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to find main function in class %s\n", mainclass);
        return 2;
    }

    jobjectArray main_args = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, c_args, (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String"), NULL);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < c_args ; i++)
        (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, main_args, i, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, args[i]));

    int result = 0;
    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cls, mid, main_args);
    if ((*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env)) { // check if an exception occurred
        (*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env); // print the stack trace
        result = -1;
    }

    (*vm)->DestroyJavaVM(vm);
    [pool drain];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In macOS/Cocoa UI operations have to be on the main thread. Are you calling your `launchjvm` function from there?

Comment: @user2543253 yes, and to be sure, I just encapsulated this funtionality inside a selecator called through  `performSelectorOnMainThread`

Comment: Wait, I think it was the other way round. When you're using SWT you need to start the VM on the main thread (what `-XstartOnFirstThread` does for the java launcher), if not you mustn't, because the AWT event queue has to be separate from the main *Java* thread. Been a while since I implemented our launcher. You might check the OpenJDK launcher code for reference.

Comment: That's how it is done on the OpenJDK launcher, that's where I copied the idea of `performSelectorOnMainThread`. Thanks for the tip though. And I am not using SWT, but Swing (i.e. AWT/Cocoa)

Comment: Not using SWT you can't start the JVM on the main thread, because AWT will hang. Couldn't find the relevant code in JDK11 but it's on line 81 in `JavaAppLauncher.m` in JDK8 (`startOnFirstThread` is for non-AWT only), so *not* using `performSelectorOnMainThread` should fix it

Comment: I tried both ways :( doesn't work. Also, it doesn't hang, it goes on. I just can't see any window pop-up.